# Python uic.loadUi doesnt recongise button group

Tags: python, pyqt, buttongroup, loadui

I have previously use the following steps to load PyQt ui into python. 

1.Use designer to create the ui file

2.Go to dos and use pyuic4 to convert the ui files into python(MyQtUI.py)

3.Import in the python files

```
from MyQtUI import UI_Mainwindow

Class MyUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=none): 
        QtGui.Qwidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.comboBox_Title.addItems("a","b","c")
        .
        .
        .
    def check_radioButtonStatus(self):
        print self.ui.radioBtnGrp_confirmed.checkedButton().objectName()
```

I have no problem running the above code but when i tried the other method which is using uic.loadUi, my button group could not be recognized.

```
Class MyUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=none): 
        QtGui.Qwidget.__init__(self,parent)
        uic.loadUi('MyQtUi.ui',self)
        self.comboBox_Title.addItems("a","b","c") <--- no problem here
        .
        .
        .
    def check_radioButtonStatus(self):
        print self.radioBtnGrp_confirmed.checkedButton().objectName() <--- object has no attribute 'radioBtnGrp_confirmed'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Some possibilities: 1) You redefined self (same as you did in the first example),  2) You need to call setupUi()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. self is already define in the loadUi function as the 2nd parameter and setupUi() is a function from the python file. As I'm trying to load the ui file directly without importing the python file, I wont have setupUi() to use.

Comment: Did you mean `self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()` and `self.ui.setupUi(self)` in the 1st example ?

Comment: Concerning the 2nd example, either you deleted the object somewhere,  either it is not in the ui file.